# PyInstaller creates __pycache__ instead of dist

Tags: python, utf-8, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a standalone executable for my python code. I followed everything in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-lKHA9o_pY&t=158s) but it doesn't create a dist folder. It creates a folder called **pycache** and when I click the document inside it, it says:

'The file's encoding is invalid for Python 3.x. IDLE will convert it to UTF-8. What is the current encoding of this file?'

When I click OK with utf-8 as the answer, it says Failed to decode.

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use auto-py-to-exe instead:
To instal this type:

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

Next just type:

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

Into the terminal and it will be pretty straightforward from then on.

Comment: This gives me the following error: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-core' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Project output will not be moved to output folder

Comment: Thats weird, I use it on a Mac

Comment: https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi

Comment: Try that website

Comment: I've got an exec file now but it doesn't really do anything as it gives me the following: [14689] Error loading Python lib 'some/very/long/weird/path' logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

Answer (score -1):

The 'dist' folder and the exe file are created in C:\Users\user directory.